# Testing debounced function in React component with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am testing a React component using Jest and Enzyme, and am having difficulty testing that a debounced function is called properly (or at all). I've simplified the component code below (edited to make code even simpler), link to codepen [here](https://codepen.io/TDB2/pen/WaojYB)

```javascript
// uses lodash debounce

class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super()
    this.state = {name: "initial value"};
    this.debouncedFunction = _.debounce(this.debouncedFunction, 3000);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }
  
  debouncedFunction () {
    this.setState({name: "after delay, updated value"});
  }
  
  handleClick() {
    this.debouncedFunction();
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.name}</p>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
          click for debounced function
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I figured that the debounced function test should be pretty similar to one that is non-debounced, but with a `setTimeout` or `Promise` (with the `expect` assertion inside `.then` or `.finally`). After trying many variations of tests employing both those ideas, I'm not so sure anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: You might need to mock the timers using [this](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks.html) and use `jest.advanceTimersByTime()`. If you can provide a setup where I can write and debug the tests, I could try some approach and share a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the offer of help! I simplified my code sample and added a codepen link in my question above.

Comment: Thanks. But since jest doesn't run in the browser, I won't be able to write and validate tests. I'll try some time later maybe. But I found an answer which is in line with what I have in mind. Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/52226973/2950032

Comment: I'm not sure if it's just the simplification for display purposes, but your handler could easily just be `this.handleClick = _.debounce(this.handleClick.bind(this), 3000);` in the constructor. Then, everything is bound properly, and you could test the click handler in isolation.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**NOTE**: this answer also applies to  [`lodash.throttle`](https://lodash.com/docs/#throttle) since it is just a wrapper of `debounce`.

Lodash's [`debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce) is a monster and needs some special treatments in test because not only does it use `setTimeout()` but it also:

- [Calls](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/86a852fe763935bb64c12589df5391fd7d3bb14d/debounce.js#L147) [`setTimeout()`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/86a852fe763935bb64c12589df5391fd7d3bb14d/debounce.js#L153) [recursively](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/86a852fe763935bb64c12589df5391fd7d3bb14d/debounce.js#L107): This means calling `jest.runAllTimers()` to mock `setTimeout` will lead to infinite recursion error, since mocked `setTimeout()` executes synchronously until it runs out of task, which is not the case here.
- [Uses](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/86a852fe763935bb64c12589df5391fd7d3bb14d/debounce.js#L185) [`Date`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/86a852fe763935bb64c12589df5391fd7d3bb14d/debounce.js#L148) [API](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/86a852fe763935bb64c12589df5391fd7d3bb14d/debounce.js#L177): Jest v25 and below only mocks timer functions (e.g. `setTimeout`, `setInterval`) while `debounce` uses both `setTimeout` and `Date` so we need to mock both of them.

How you fix this problem depend on what version of jest you are using.

#### For jest version 25 and below:

Use another library to mock `Date` object. In this example I'll use `advanceBy()` from [`jest-date-mock`](https://github.com/hustcc/jest-date-mock)

```js
jest.useFakeTimers()

await act(async () => {
  triggerDebounced()
  advanceBy(DEBOUNCED_TIME + 1000) // forward Date
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(DEBOUNCED_TIME) // forward setTimeout's timer
})
```

#### Jest version 26:

Jest [version 26](https://github.com/facebook/jest/releases/tag/v26.0.0) introduces modern mode for fake timers which mocks both `Date` and timer functions, it's an opt-in feature, so in order to use it you need to add `jest.useFakeTimers('modern')` before the test runs

```js
jest.useFakeTimers("modern")

await act(async () => {
  triggerDebounced()
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(DEBOUNCED_TIME)
})
```

#### Jest version 27+:

According to this [PR](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/7776#issue-249656276), Jest v27 will use the modern implementation by default so we don't need to specify it explicitly.

```js
jest.useFakeTimers()

await act(async () => {
  triggerDebounced()
  jest.advanceTimersByTime(DEBOUNCED_TIME)
})
```